# How can I specify datadir when installing mysql on ubuntu?

Tags: mysql

I just have another disk mounted at `/mnt/mysql`, I want to use it as mysql's datadir. How can I do this?
Currently I have no data in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit your /etc/mysql/my.conf. Look for "DataDir" and change that to the path you want. Save the file, and then restart your mysql service.